# FTP zip file extract Error

Tags: java, exception, zip

I am trying to extract zip files from the server(A zip file is in the server.so I am trying to extract that through the FTP) and I am using this code,

```
  byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

    ZipInputStream zinstream = new ZipInputStream(Home.ftpClient.retrieveFileStream("HO2BR.br.3162675983055490721.zync"));
    ZipEntry zentry = zinstream.getNextEntry();
    System.out.println("Name of current Zip Entry : " + zentry + "\n");
    while (zentry != null) {
        String entryName = zentry.getName();
        System.out.println("Name of  Zip Entry : " + entryName);
        FileOutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(entryName);
        int n;

        while ((n = zinstream.read(buf, 0, 1024)) > -1) {
            outstream.write(buf, 0, n);

        }
        System.out.println("Successfully Extracted File Name : " + entryName);
        outstream.close();

        zinstream.closeEntry();
        zentry = zinstream.getNextEntry();
    }
    zinstream.close();

}
```

*ZipInputStream(Home.ftpClient.retrieveFileStream("HO2BR.br.3162675983055490721.zync"));*
  to Input stream assign the *FTPClient*  's retrieveFileStream

while executing the  program this error is occurred

java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)

How can I solve this exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the `ftpClient.retrieveFileStream` does not support seeking. The Zip "table of contents" entries occur at the very end of the file. So, "opening" the first item requires the ability to back up to the start of the file to read that item.

You'll need to download the zip file to a local file, then extract the contents from there.

Comment: hi, it is possible to extract zip file from the server,i mean without download the file and I need to extract that to the server.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to change the transfer mode from `ASCII` to `BINARY`